# Advisor suggested me to typeset my thesis with a software that I don't know

Tags: thesis, latex

I am writing my dissertation and my supervisor recommended me this LaTeX template.

https://bitbucket.org/amiede/classicthesis/wiki/Home

However, I have been using MS-Word all along and don't know LaTeX. What are some approaches I can consider given this situation?

Comment: Google for `thesis template filetype:doc` and find something that seems acceptable.

Comment: This is not the right place asking for technical formatting help, but I have revised your question to make it read more like an academic life problem, as I do think your question has some essence that'd be useful for this site. Hopefully people may retract their close votes.

Comment: Your course of action depends on how closely you need to conform to the recommended formatting. If really closely, there is no substitute for learning latex and using the template. If it is just a general suggestion, you could ask your supervisor to recommend some well-formatted dissertations and copy their style. If you intend a career that involves a lot of paper-writing, this may be a good time to learn latex anyway.

Comment: I think "how to get your thesis done" is very much ON TOPIC.  This is not a microscopic question about a particular software but a general question on approach.

Comment: MA:  My advise is to stick to Word if that is easier for you.  I did so on my thesis and had way less issues than some people who dove into LATEX.  There is a set of people who are good at it, advocate it, etc. (not surprisingly strongly represented at Stack Exchange).  But if you are familiar with a normal word processing software, diving into LATEX when you just want to get your thesis done is a hassle.  I vote to ignore the advice (not an order) from your advisor and stick with what tool you are already using.

Comment: The template in the link appears to be fairly generic, so presumably another generic template will work. But asking the advisor is the only way to resolve any uncertainties. I think this is off-topic, as the only possible answers are “ask your advisor” and “figure out an alternative”.

Comment: Latex is a pretty good environment, and you may have to learn it eventually if you want to continue working in academia. If you have enough time to work on your thesis, equip yourself with a book about latex (for example, google for 'lshort') and give it a try.

Comment: Write in absolutely whatever software you want. If your advisor would prefer you used X, say you'd prefer to focus on your research rather than learn a new document preparation system. If they insist you really must use something else, ask if you can just give them a PDF or a printed version; if they really insist anything final be prepped in a specific software, then keep writing in whatever you want as you learn the bare minimum to copy-paste into their preferred format when it is time to send them something. If you decide to learn a new system, sure, go for it - but don't get bogged down.

Comment: As background, in the writing process I've used a mixture of Word, Google Docs, Notepad, ShareLaTeX/Overleaf, scraps of paper, pictures from a smartphone (often of whiteboard scribblings), screen caps, code comments in half a dozen coding environments, and in a past career I did desktop publishing/commercial printing (QuarkXPress, Publisher, InDesign, and a half-dozen other weird bits) - and let me assure you, absolutely everything is awful in its own unique and terrible way. Do whatever it takes to get the thing written and move on with your life.

Comment: I don't agree that this is off-topic, but it could use some clarification and context. For example, why did your supervisor give you this template? What are other students in your program doing? And what field are you in?

Comment: I think the TEX versus word processing is a good general question and have seen it discussed (in passing) elsewhere.  It is not trivial or "ask your advisor" since the decision is really up to the student in most cases.  It is a question of should I use what is comfortable or bother learning some new system while also dealing with the content itself. (My vote is no.)  Finally it differs a lot by field (math/CS/physics types seem comfortable with TEX and push it.)  Rest of the world hates it because it feels like writing in computer goblidigook, not English.

Comment: If you choose to follow Allure's advice. I suggest you see this site http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: Assuming you don't want to learn latex, this question seems to boil down to "how do I use Word to produce a document that looks like this?". That feels like too big a question to answer on stackexchange...

Answer (score 20):

Learn how to use LaTeX.

LaTeX is not hard. If you have any experience programming you'll probably find LaTeX extremely elementary. You can conceivably have issues rendering certain characters or equations, but Google is likely to easily find solutions to that. TeX is also quite powerful as a word processing tool, allowing you to write obscure symbols (for example, \cdot) easily. This doesn't mean LaTeX is better than Word; certainly some things are easier done in Word than TeX. But knowing both means you have an additional weapon in your arsenal, and you'll have a better idea which weapon to deploy given what you intend to write in your dissertation.

Comment: While you're at it, learn how to use some of the many tools that work with LaTeX, starting with the BibTex system for bibliographies.  Also find a good reference manager such as Zotero.

Comment: We also have a [Tex.SE] stack exchange.

Comment: I strongly recommend learning LaTeX if the OP will stay in academia/research (and doing so whilst writing a dissertation is an excellent time to do so), but it probably isn't worth the effort if the OP is leaving academia/research (after their dissertation).

Comment: OP should learn how to use LaTeX, but LaTeX is _very_ hard. Sure, following the simple examples isn't, but anything beyond trivial, any bit of customization is rather hellish, and the ecosphere is difficult to wrap your mind around.

Comment: @user2768: It is well worth the effort if OP ever wants to write anything seriously, academia or no.

Comment: There are a gazillion people writing things without ever using Tex.  Word is the norm for journalists, office workers and academics outside of math, physics and computer science.

Comment: "LaTeX is not hard" might be overstating things. Sure, it's not terribly difficult for someone who has exposure to programming, but the OP hasn't given us an idea of his field. I suspect LaTeX would be much harder for someone writing a history dissertation vs a math one.

Comment: @AzorAhai Tools such as LyX can help

Comment: Good advice. Let me suggest this site http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Answer (score 6):

First, the repository you linked to has a PDF showing exactly what the template looks like. So, there is really no issue, you can follow that template in whatever typesetting system you want. This technically answers the question you asked -- you can follow your advisor's instructions and still use Word. I hate to see you waste time recreating everything in Word when it already exists in LaTeX, however.

A better option would be to search for thesis templates written in Word. Depending on how flexible your advisor is, you could either tweak the templates until they look like the one your advisor wanted, or you could sit with your advisor to find one you both like, or you could just find one you like and see whether he complains.

An even better option, assuming you are in STEM, would be to learn LaTeX. This is something you should know anyway if you are getting a STEM degree. You'll be able to copy-and-paste your existing text into LaTeX (with some minor modifications); you don't have to type it all out again. Assuming you know how to program, you'll learn LaTeX in about 90 minutes -- read chapters 2 and 3 of "The Not So Short Guide to LaTeX." If you don't know how to program, this will be a heavier lift, but it's still a low-effort, high-reward endeavor.

One last point -- are you sure your institution doesn't have a required thesis format? Most universities I'm familiar with are very particular about how thesis should be formatted, especially the front matter -- mine even had institutional templates floating around, in both Word and LaTeX.

Edit: One last, last point: Elizabeth makes an interesting distinction between a writing program (where you write your content) and a typesetting program (where you make it look nice). If you share this concern, you could always continue to do your drafting in Word, and then set aside a few days at the end to TeX-ify it (or hire someone to do so). I personally would find it more efficient to use TeX end-to-end, but to each their own.

Comment: My institution was also very particular about the thesis format, which they changed slightly on a fairly regular basis (just to make it harder on us, I guess). Page numbers had to be a specific distance from margins, different amounts for chapters and front matter, etc. They sent it back to me to edit it to fit requirements like 8 times (and they allowed a maximum of 9 I think). Sometimes fixing one thing had weird impacts elsewhere, but mostly they simply didn't point out everything that was wrong at once.  Just found one thing, bounced it back over that, rinse and repeat.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Didn't staff at your university have better things to do than being overly pedantic on the format of a thesis?

Comment: @o4tlulz Apparently not.  I'm fairly sure it was the explicit job of at least one person there.

Answer (score -5):

The issue here isn't whether LaTeX is hard to learn. The issue is that a LaTeX editor is a terrible writing environment when compared to a word processor. Some people are bothered by this and some are not, and which side you're on is entirely a matter of personal preference.

What is not a matter of personal preference is the expectations of your supervisor and your field. Some fields (and some supervisors) regard producing LaTeX-typeset documents to be matter of professional necessity. Others just think it looks nice, or they like the tech-cred pretentions. So it's impossible to give a good answer to your question without knowing what your context is.

EDIT: This doesn't add much to answering the OP's question, but judging by the comments there seems to be some confusion about what a word processor is for, as well as about what a downvote is for.

Word processors were specifically designed for *writing* documents, and have features such as outline view, tracking changes, commenting sidebars, etc. Moreover, many writers use formatting features such as highlighting and font color as part of their writing process.

TeX on the other hand was specifically designed for *typesetting* documents, and the introduction of LaTeX and its variants made it a marginally usable system for *writing* documents. But the standard LaTeX front ends don't have the features of a word processor and many people find having to read around markup cumbersome and distracting. For these reasons, using a word processor is an objectively better environment for writing.

Of course, many other people are perfectly happy writing in a text editor and don't mind reading around markup. But this doesn't make you smarter, "more efficient," or a superior human being. It just means that you have a different work process.

The point for the OP is that being expected to trade Word for LaTeX is generally a lousy deal, but there might be constraining or mitigating factors in any particular situation.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88962/discussion-on-answer-by-elizabeth-henning-advisor-suggested-me-to-typeset-my-the).